# Query child entity based on parnet id - Jhipster query

Tags: angular, jpa, jhipster

I'm using Jhipster 4 with angular 2 to create application. I would like to show tabs where on Parent entity user will have tabs with child entity lists.
Customer and User will have tabs with Tasks and Addresses. I know how to put them into tabs and select list using separate findByUserId() and findByCustomerId().

I would like to avoid creating those method for each parent element, like **findByPersonId()**.

1. Is it possible to send query to repository.findAll()? can I utilize **query(req?: any): Observable {}** in **task.service.ts** to get data for tabs.
   To do something like; "where user.id=X" or "where customer.id=X".
2. If it is possible, how I can pass query option directly from [routerLink] to query()
3. Is it any clear method to do it?

   entity Customer {
       name String required,
   }

   entity Person {
       name String required,
   }

   entity Task {
       name String required
   }
   entity Adres {
       name String required
   }

   relationship OneToMany {
       Customer{tasks} to Task{customer(name)},
       Person{tasks} to Task{person(name)}
   }

in **task.service.ts**

```
 query(req?: any): Observable<Response> {
        let options = this.createRequestOption(req);
        return this.http.get(this.resourceUrl, options)
            .map((res: any) => this.convertResponse(res))
        ;
    }

    ...
    private createRequestOption(req?: any): BaseRequestOptions {
        let options: BaseRequestOptions = new BaseRequestOptions();
        if (req) {
            let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
            params.set('page', req.page);
            params.set('size', req.size);
            if (req.sort) {
                params.paramsMap.set('sort', req.sort);
            }
            params.set('query', req.query);

            options.search = params;
        }
        return options;
    }
```

**TaskRepository.ts**

```
/**
 * Spring Data JPA repository for the Task entity.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task,Long> {

    @Query("select task from Task task where person.id =:id")
    public List<Task>  findByPersonId(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Query("select task from Task task where customer.id =:id")
    public List<Task>  findByCustomerId(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

**TaskResource.ts**

```
 /**
     * GET  /tasks : get all the tasks.
     *
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the list of tasks in body
     */
    @GetMapping("/tasks")
    @Timed
    public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
        log.debug("REST request to get all Tasks");
        List<Task> tasks = taskRepository.findAll();
        return tasks;
    }
```